# Pregunta puesta en espera por un usuario que votó por dejarla abierta

Tags: soporte, votos-de-cierre, revisiones

[Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83923/c%C3%B3mo-usar-mercadopago-en-modo-sandbox) ha sido puesta en espera, pero me ha surgido una duda con respecto a los votos, el mensaje y quién votó qué.

En la pregunta se muestra el mensaje de que la pregunta ha sido puesta en espera y se indica quiénes hemos sido los usuarios que lo hicieron:  Shaz, Ivan Botero, toledano, Rubén y Alvaro Montoro (yo mismo).

[image: Pregunta puesta en espera por...]

Sin embargo, mirando en la [revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close/53047) y en el historial de revisiones, se puede ver que Rubén votó por dejar abierta la pregunta:

[image: Voto de Rubén para dejar la pregunta abierta]

¿Por qué su nombre aparece como "causante" del cierre de la pregunta? ¿Es éste el comportamiento esperado en el mensaje?

Comment: @ArtEze Me refiero a ese afán de cerrar preguntas, de marcarlas como duplicadas, de sobrevolar preguntas (crear preguntas _más completas_) para cerrar otras, etc. [En este mismo caso que nos ocupa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/83923/29967), varios usuarios votaron para cerrarla y nadie ha señalado al OP el **error ortográfico** que hay en el código (`true` y no `ture`) y que podría ser el causante de su problema. Eso sí, hasta abrimos discusiones en Meta sobre la pregunta y todo. No me parece correcto que se ignore en cierto sentido el problema planteado.

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo de crear preguntas más completas, ahora lo entiendo, trataré de evitar que suceda nuevamente ese tipo de cosas en lo que me resta por ser moderador. En esta pregunta en concreto, la pregunta se cerró porque nadie entendía lo que preguntaban. Fuiste el único que se dio cuenta del error de tipeo, creo que fuiste muy atento.

Comment: @A.Cedano por lo que dice OP, esa es la respuesta que está recibiendo desde MercadoPago y no lo que manda a MercadoPago ("_me devuelve el parámetro live_mode en true_"), por lo que sería un error al copiar a la pregunta. Aparte, "¿Funcionará A con B?" es una pregunta de baja calidad, OP tiene todo para probar si funciona; nosotros, no. Lo ideal sería que OP probase y luego preguntase "¿Por qué [sí/no] funciona A con B?"

Comment: Algo de todos estos comentarios está mínimamente relacionado a la consulta de soporte realizada en esta publicación? O estamos publicando acá como que fuera un chat? En qué sentido pueden llegar a ser relevantes para quien lea está pregunta?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61932/discussion-on-question-by-alvaro-montoro-pregunta-puesta-en-espera-por-un-usuari).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Significa que Rubén:

1. llegó y revisó la pregunta en la cola de revisión, votando por dejar abierta.
2. luego, se arrepintió, o hubo algún comentario que lo hizo cambiar de parecer, o cualquier motivo posible, y fue directamente a la pregunta y votó por cerrar.

---

**Ejemplos.** Puede suceder sencillamente en todos los casos donde hay una edición en la pregunta luego de tu revisión que te hacen cambiar de parecer y optar por cerrar. Yo lo he hecho en alguna oportunidad. Aunque muy poco frecuente, puede suceder. Recuerdo una vez en la que literalmente "hice click en el botón equivocado" y volví a la pregunta para *arreglar* mi voto (no es lo deseado, no debería ocurrir). También recuerdo otra oportunidad en la que estaba convencido de dejar abierta según la había interpretado, pero luego de leer un comentario posterior del autor, entendí que estaba apuntando a algo demasiado amplio, y cambié mi opinión.

**Comportamiento.** Está bien que se muestre así. Como todo en SE, es la forma en que se deja trazabilidad de todas las acciones realizadas.

Comment: Tiene sentido. Marco esta respuesta como aceptada, a menos que venga luego @Ruben diciendo "yo no hice tal cosa"

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro acabo de revisar el historial, y hay un voto de cierre de Ruben (a menos que haya dejado el equipo desprotegido y su gemelo malvado votó por cerrar)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: Puedes dejar como aceptada esta respuesta. Perdón por la confusión.

Comment: @Rubén no te preocupes, no fue confusión, solo curiosidad. Me extrañó que apareciera tu nombre y no sabía si era un bug del sitio